# How to use promises to denormalize nested json?

Tags: javascript, json, bluebird

I'm attempting to flatten and denormalize the data. I'm not understanding how to accomplish this using promises. What am I missing?

The result I'm getting is:

```
Bob,Nancy
Bob,Nancy
```

But I want to get:

```
Bob,Sue
Bob,Nancy
```

The code:

```
var Promise = require('bluebird');

var jsonData = {
  "Parents": [{
    "Name": "Bob",
    "AllChildren": [{
      "Name": "Sue"
    }, {
      "Name": "Nancy"
    }]
  }, {
    "Name": "Ron",
    "AllChildren": [{
      "Name": "Betty"
    }, {
      "Name": "Paula"
    }]
  }, {
    "Name": "Peter",
    "AllChildren": [{
      "Name": "Mary"
    }, {
      "Name": "Sally"
    }]
  }]
};


var promises = Promise.map(jsonData.Parents, function(parent) {
  var record = {};
  record.ParentName = parent.Name;
  var allRecords = Promise.map(parent.AllChildren, function(child) {
    var fullRecord = record;
    fullRecord.ChildName = child.Name;
    return fullRecord;
  });
  return Promise.all(allRecords);
});

console.log(JSON.stringify(promises, null, 2));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are missing here is, that promises are "promised values" that will be evaluated as soon as you "then" them. The values/promises returned within a promise chain traverse it and are fetched by the next then handler.

UPDATE: Use concat in flatten

Change your implementation like this:

```
return Promise.map(jsonData.Parents, function(parent) {
  return Promise.map(parent.AllChildren, function(child) {
    return { ParentName: parent.Name, ChildName: child.Name };
  });
})
.reduce(function (accumulator, item){
  // Flatten the inner arrays
  return accumulator.concat(item);
}, [])
.then(function (flattened) {
  console.log(JSON.stringify(flattened, null, 2));
});
```

Comment: You can console.log the chain value at every point by adding `.tap(console.log)` anywhere in the chain. That will make you understand what's going on more easy.

Answer (score 0):

Without using promises you could do try:

```
jsonData.Parents.reduce(
    function(p, c){
        var children = c.AllChildren.map(
                         function (item){
                           return {ParentName:c.Name, ChildName: item.Name};
                         });
        return p.concat(children);
    }, []);
```